# Re-rendering issues when loading all pdf pages in "react-pdf"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

I am trying to load all the pages but it goes into infinate loop(basically re-rendering).
`React.memo` is not helping me here.

```
const PdfRender = React.memo(({ pdfURL, pages, setPages }: any) => (
  <Document
    file={{
      url: pdfURL,
    }}
    onLoadSuccess={(info) => {
      setPages(new Array(info._pdfInfo.numPages).fill(info._pdfInfo.numPages));
    }}
  >
    {pages.map((_: any, i: number) => {
      return <Page pageNumber={i + 1} />;
    })}
  </Document>
));
```

I think, the re-rendering behaviour is logically correct because `onLoadSuccess` will get fire when the content is updated. As a result `setPages` and `pages` also get updated and `pages` re-renders the same pages again and `onLoadSuccess` will get fire again.(a loop basically)

But there has be any solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add a custom props check in the second argument of `React.memo`.

The `memo` HOC will only shallowly compare complex objects in the props object.

Example:

```
const PdfRender = React.memo(({ pdfURL, pages, setPages }: any) => (
  <Document
    file={{
      url: pdfURL,
    }}
    onLoadSuccess={(info) => {
      setPages(new Array(info._pdfInfo.numPages).fill(info._pdfInfo.numPages));
    }}
  >
    {pages.map((_: any, i: number) => {
      return <Page pageNumber={i + 1} />;
    })}
  </Document>
), (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
});
```

[SOURCE](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)